# PuppeteerSharp: Failed to launch browser after switching to Alpine Linux

Tags: .net, dockerfile, chromium, puppeteer-sharp

I had the PuppeteerSharp working with the Debian distro but now I need to run with a [wolfi-base distro](https://github.com/wolfi-dev) that is Alpine. You can read more about it [here](https://www.chainguard.dev/unchained/introducing-wolfi-the-first-linux-un-distro).

On my docker file, I had installed the following dependencies:

```yaml
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y xorg openbox libnss3 libasound2
```

And this worked fine. I look what I can install that is similar and got:

```yaml
RUN apk update && apk add xorg-server openbox nss alsa-lib
```

But now I cannot launch the browser and I believe this because now I have missing dependencies:

> Unhandled exception. PuppeteerSharp.ProcessException: Failed to launch browser!

Here is how I launch it on my .net 8 application:

```cs
private static async Task<IBrowser> GetAndLaunchOsMatchingBrowser()
{
    var browserFetcher = new BrowserFetcher();

    await browserFetcher.DownloadAsync(BrowserFetcher.DefaultChromiumRevision);

    var launchOptions = new LaunchOptions
    {
        Args = new[] { "--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox" },
        Headless = true,
        ExecutablePath = Path.Combine(browserFetcher.RevisionInfo(BrowserFetcher.DefaultChromiumRevision).ExecutablePath)
    };

    return await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(launchOptions);
}
```

I cannot download Chromium directly and point to the path to launch it. Are there any dependencies I need to run it?
Thank you!

Edit: After digging in the logs I got

> error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score -1):

You're missing some libs to support the browser runtime:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libatk1.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libcups2 libdrm2 libxkbcommon0 libxcomposite1 libxdamage1 libxrandr2 libgbm1 libpango-1.0-0 libcairo2 libasound2 libxshmfence1 libnss3 libxss1
```

Comment: I can only use apk, and I don't have those dependencies there...